# How to disable APC in Symfony?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm running a project on Symfony 1.4. Ported it to Windows. Was on a Linux server.
Get this error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfInitializationException
You must have APC installed and enabled to use sfAPCCache class.
```

So I know that there is not an easy way to install APC on Windows. I wanna to temporary disable APC in this project. Which files should I change to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `factories.yml` in `apps/yourapp/config`. Most probably one of the factories uses the APC cache. You can disable it or try to change to a different cache engine.

According to Sf docs these are the built in cache classes:

```
 sfAPCCache, sfEAcceleratorCache, sfFileCache, sfMemcacheCache, sfNoCache, sfSQLiteCache, and sfXCacheCache
```

In fact it's not that difficult to install APC on Windows (I managed to do it a while ago ;) ). If you google for "APC cache windows" you can find a few comprehensive instructions on how to do it.